# how to fix not able to clone a repository by ssh in gitlab

Tags: git, gitlab, clone, ssh-keys, git-clone

I want to clone a repository by SSH after specifying Ssh-key to the user but there is no action when I clone the repository. namely, I run the below command but the request for username and password is not presented and stays in the loading state.
How can I fix the problem?

```
git clone git@xxx.com:test-environment/test.git
```

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure your SSH public key is correctly uploaded in your GitLab profile.

Besides, have you tried using `ssh://git@xxx.com:test-environment/test.git` ?

You can also check your SSH via:

```
ssh -T git@xxx.com
```